# is this the right way for doing aggregation in elasticsearch using spring data template

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have a type in elasticsearch which has field called `created` (which is a date). I need to do a `dateHistogram` aggregation on this field. Is this the right way? Can someone provide me a better code snippet?

```
    List<Result> results = new ArrayList<>();
    NativeSearchQueryBuilder nativeSearchQueryBuilder = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder();
    RangeFilterBuilder rangeBuilderForDate = FilterBuilder.getRangeBuilderForDate(searchCriteria.getCreatedFrom(), searchCriteria.getCreatedTo(), Field.CREATED.getFieldName());

    TermFilterBuilder statusTermFilter = FilterBuilder.getTermFilter("Active", Field.STATUS.getFieldName());

    BoolFilterBuilder boolFilterBuilder = boolFilter();
    BoolFilterBuilder should = boolFilterBuilder.must(rangeBuilderForDate, statusTermFilter);
    DateHistogramBuilder dateAggs = AggregationBuilders.dateHistogram("created").interval(getInterval(searchCriteria)).field("created");

    FiltersAggregationBuilder filterAggs = AggregationBuilders.filters("dateRange").filter(should).subAggregation(dateAggs);
    NativeSearchQuery searchQuery = nativeSearchQueryBuilder.withIndices(index).withTypes(type).addAggregation(filterAggs).build();
    Aggregations aggregations = template.query(searchQuery, new ResultsExtractor<Aggregations>() {
        @Override
        public Aggregations extract(SearchResponse response) {
            return response.getAggregations();
        }
    });

    Map<String, Aggregation> asMap = aggregations.getAsMap();
    InternalFilters aggregation = (InternalFilters)asMap.get("dateRange");
    Collection<Bucket> buckets = aggregation.getBuckets();

    for(Filters.Bucket filterBuckets : buckets) {
        Aggregations subAggs = filterBuckets.getAggregations();
        InternalDateHistogram dateSubAggs = (InternalDateHistogram) subAggs.asMap().get("created");
        for(Histogram.Bucket bucket : dateSubAggs.getBuckets()) {
            Result result = new Result();
            DateHistogram.Bucket dateBucket = (DateHistogram.Bucket) bucket;
            result.setAggCriteria(dateBucket.getKey());
            result.setCount(dateBucket.getDocCount());
            results.add(result);
        }
    }
    return results;
```